# C# File.AppendText(path) Access to path denied

Tags: c#, windows, file, io, file-permissions

I know this is a common problem with a lot of related topics on here. But none of them seem to work for me.

I have code that works on a production system that I've copied across to my local home computer:

```
 private static void WriteToLog(string logText, string logPath)
        {
            try
            {
                using (StreamWriter outputFile = File.AppendText(logPath))
                {
                    outputFile.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + "|| " + Regex.Replace(logText, @"\t|\n|\r", ""));
                }
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                //what do?
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

The line  `using (StreamWriter outputFile = File.AppendText(logPath))` throws the classic exception:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path
> 'C:\Users\Jaso\Documents\DataChecker_Logs\schema_a-academic_attainment.txt'
> is denied.'

At runtime the path variable contains `"C:\\Users\\Jaso\\Documents\\DataChecker_Logs\\schema_a-academic_attainment.txt"`

The Security of the folder in question looks like this:

[image]

When I find the user the process is run under using `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;`, the value returned is `"DESKTOP-LMMBET3\\Jaso"` which according to the folder's settings (above screenshot) is a principal with full control!!

Windows 10 machine.

GRRR!!!

Comment: "But none of them seem to work for me." ... so you tried running VS in Admin Mode and still receive this exception?  what exactly have you tried?

Comment: yup tried running in admin mode, tried granting access but the process's user already has access, the rest of solutions I found relate to people mistakenly trying to overwrite an entire folder or not including the filename in the path etc. which dont apply to me @BrettCaswell

Comment: how are you calling `WriteToLog`? is your program creating a `Shell` or doing `Process` that invokes the method?

Comment: @BrettCaswell not sure what  a Shell is but a method in the code calls this method so I think doing a Process that invokes

Answer (score 0):

Check the permission of the file itself not the folder

[image: Check the permission of the file itself]

if you don't have the permission  to access the file this error will  be thrown

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException
```

[image]

Comment: it's a new file, like empty folder and File.Append is creating the file from scratch?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.filesecurity?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0

Comment: Check this may help you